# Reading sqlite multithreading options in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite

I am trying to determine if my java sqlite jdbc driver is compiled in single-thread, multi-thread or serial mode.

I found these references for C:
https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html
https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/threadsafe.html

But i could not figure out how to do this in Java.

I am using sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar.

We downgraded to this version because we had crashes with 3.8.7 and 3.8.6 was supposed to be more stable (which we can not yet confirm).

I already tried to get the desired information using PRAGMA queries, but i could not find a corresponding PRAGMA-setting.

The following code does not work on my system since the classes i have do not have the mentioned methods and the SQLiteSwigged does not exist at all (from https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/4875442/)

```
System.out.println("_SQLiteSwigged.sqlite3_libversion()=" + _SQLiteSwigged.sqlite3_libversion());
System.out.println("_SQLiteSwigged.sqlite3_libversion_number()=" + _SQLiteSwigged.sqlite3_libversion_number());
System.out.println("_SQLiteSwigged.sqlite3_threadsafe()=" + _SQLiteSwigged.sqlite3_threadsafe());
System.out.println("_SQLiteSwigged.sqlite3_memory_used()=" + _SQLiteSwigged.sqlite3_memory_used());
```

This class (which has a isThreadSafe() method) also does not exist in my current setup: http://sqlitejdbc.sourceforge.jp/org/sqlite/Database.html
(This API seems to be an old version of crawshaw's project http://freecode.com/projects/sqlitejdbc)

Comment: Your problem is not clear. What you actually want.

Comment: I want to know how to query the setting for SQLITE_THREADSAFE (as described here https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/threadsafe.html for C) in Java for the jdbc-library i am using.